# ¿ Como iniciar el mapa de Here Maps oculto y al mostrarse no se vea correctamente? [Angular 7, Here-maps]

Tags: javascript, angular7

Estoy haciendo uso del here maps en Angular 7, el problema esta en que necesito el mapa cargado previamente antes de mostrarlo.
Lo que hace actualmente es mostrar los controles y el mapa se muestra en blanco.

Este es el código que uso para iniciar el mapa

```
    let me = this;
    let defaultLayers = this.platform.createDefaultLayers();
    me.map = new H.Map(
          me.mapElement.nativeElement,
          defaultLayers.normal.map,
          {
            zoom: 10,
            center: { lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng }
          }
        );
        let behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(this.map));
        this.router = this.platform.getRoutingService();
        this.ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(this.map, defaultLayers, 'es-ES');
        this.ui.getControl('panorama').setVisibility(false);
        this.cargarMarks();
```

[image: Se puede observar como se ve]

Intente después de mostrar el div usar esta linea

```
this.map.getViewPort().resize();
```

pero sigue sin funcionar. Si se carga después de estar visible el div,funciona correctamente

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bastó con poner un setTimeout para utilizar esta linea

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.map.getViewPort().resize();
  }, 500);
```

Esto funciono para mi espero ayudar a alguien con esta respuesta.